# Sync View Controller 'present' and 'VisualEffectView animation'

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I'm pushing a `viewcontroller` with animation. I want to sync the duration of `UIVisualEffectView` with duration of animation during the present.

So as result the visual effect animation will be started just after the view controller *push*, and the same will be ended when the present animation is completed. How to achieve this animation.

Code I have written so far is below.

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect()
let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
visualEffectView.frame = view.frame

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
   visualEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
}
view.addSubview(visualEffectView)
// present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Note**: I'm presenting over the current context only.

Comment: You have to make custom animation with UIPresentationController and present view controller using transiotion you've created. Another way to achieve that is to animate view of both controllers on viewDidAppear and viewDidDisapper life cycle's functions.